# Set ionic v3 button height to take 100% height in a row

Tags: android, button, ionic-framework, flexbox

I'm developing an Android app with ionic framework v3, and I'm trying to get the buttons to take the 100% height of the row they are in, but I'm failing to do so. The result so far is 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKx8i.png).

This is the relevant part in my home.html:

```
<ion-content  scroll="false">
  <section class = "home-container">
  <ion-row class="first-row">
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button block>
          Button 1
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button block>
          Button 2
      </button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row class="second-row">
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button block>
          Button 3
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button block>
          Button 4
      </button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  </section>
</ion-content>
```

and my home.scss:

```
.home-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.home-container > .row {
    flex: 1;
}

.first-row {
    flex: 0.5 !important;
    background-color: #aeeeee;
}

.second-row {
    flex: 1.5 !important;
    background-color: #feeeee;
}

.button-md {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that with **css only**:

```css
.home-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.home-container > .row {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0;
}

.first-row {
    flex: 0.5 !important;
    background-color: #aeeeee;
}

.second-row {
    flex: 1.5 !important;
    background-color: #feeeee;
}

ion-col {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
}

.button-md {
    height: auto;
}
```

Pay a special attention to:

1. `ion-col { display: flex; }`
2. `.button-md { height: auto; }`

Result:

[image]

(I used padding in the columns (`ion-col`), but you can remove if along with the button margins it you want the buttons occupying exactly 100% of the row).

**Update**

I tested in a Moto G2 (real device) with Android 6.0 and worked fine too:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, did you checked it on device? I tested it on emulator, but it seems not working :(

Comment: @Yerkon I tested in a real Android 6.0 device and worked fine too (see the update).

Comment: Suppose, if we want first and second row height to be the same. For example 50% first row and 50% second row.
2. If quantity of rows more than two? If 4 rows, then each one should take 25% of height.
By rows i mean button height also

Comment: Look at `flex: 0.5 !important;` in the first row and `flex: 1.5 !important;` in the second. This means the 2nd will be 3 times bigger than the 1st. You could try with `flex 1` in all rows (or just remove the 2 lines I said above, because 1 is the default) and see if it works for you.

Comment: I have little different case problem than this, Thanks Lucas, after some experimenting it works :) Interesing that css which works in browser, doesn't the same in webview. Voted

Comment: @Yerkon That might be due to the version of the webview. In the Android browser I can use `input` of type `file` with the `multiple` property and it works, in the webview I can choose only one file at a time, in the same device. This is probably because the webview chromium version is older than the one used by the browser.